# How can I compute the information (or entropy) contained in a string of bits?

Tags: entropy

How can I compute the information (or entropy) contained in a string of bits?

- **Shannon's equation for entropy** is not the solution, it just counts the 1 & 0, so for the string:
  010101...
  I get maximum entropy, even thou the string is highly ordered and hence it contains a small amount of information.
- **Auto-encoders** seam helpful, but you can't tell how much information they "steal", in other words how much they over-fit. For example, if I train it on an N-bits long string with an N-1 input length, it would just memorize every single bit, resulting in 0 information as output.
- I know that the best that a **compression algorithm** can do is to reach maximum entropy, and the resulting information is the length of the output string, but I don't think this generalizes well, plus what would such algorithm be?

Does it have something to do with Shannon's entropy computed on n-tuples for n = 1...N ?

My best guess is to use the matrix of probabilities that an n-bits long sub-string "i" will follow an other ("j").

Can anybody help?

Comment: Entropy and derived quantities such as information are always defined for a probability distribution over states of a system. *You* decide what the states of the system are (that you care about), and then you measure the probability of each state occurring and determine the entropy given the full probability distribution. All of this is to say that you need to define what the states are, i.e. what sequences (and of what length) of bits you care about.

Comment: I understand, how do you define an equivalence relation between states (bit strings) then?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "equivalence relation between states"? States are distinct exactly because they are not equivalent. What I meant with my previous comment is that you need to define a dictionary of symbol combinations or "words", and then count your "word" frequencies. The only requirement information theory then puts on those frequencies is that they sum to one. There is no known natural way to construct such a dictionary (otherwise we would have found the perfect compression algorithm), so you need to define what how to construct that dictionary.

Comment: What you said about compression algorithms is not quite correct, by the way (the relationship is much weaker). The length of the output of a compression algorithm plus the combined length of the compression dictionary is proportional to an upper bound (IIRC) on the entropy contained. So it is not particular useful if you want to know the entropy/information exactly but can be helpful if you want to *compare* the information content of two documents. The algorithm that is often used is [Lempel-Ziv-Welch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), i.e. your basic `zip`.

Comment: interesting replies :) I was wondering just if the entropy S was just 
theoretically computable. I also found out that the relation between the maximum relative entropy "s" = S/S_max and the average of the bits μ is:  s(μ) <= - μ log2 (μ) - (1-μ) log2(1-μ) .

Comment: About the dictionary, I already pointed out my problem in the first point, "Shannon's equation for entropy"

Comment: About the compression algorithm, reaching max entropy is just a theoretical limit. I did not put dictionaries in account thou :P

Comment: You need to read about Kolmogorov complexity, in your example, the length of 01. Wikipedia worked for me. Then see W. H. Zurek's paper, "thermodynamic cost of computation, algorithmic complexity and the information metric." He redefines information and considers it as Shannon entropy, H, plus Kolmogorov complexity, K. It is proven that one cannot compute the function K and it's related to Godel's undecidability. But one can find an upper bound using compression algorithms.